# Why do I get a green check mark in Google Colab when exporting an image to Google Drive but no file is found in Drive?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have tested and successfully exported files from Google Colab to Google Drive, however, I am trying to export a file of data (as a .tif) after I've performed calculations on Landsat data in Google Colab and I get a green checkmark after running the code but then there is no file in Drive. Why do I get the green check mark if the code is not executing? Or am I trying to export the information incorrectly? I have tried the two options below based on [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/worldbank/OpenNightLights/blob/master/onl/tutorials/mod3_7_import_export_data.ipynb#scrollTo=sg1d2W7dGQJy).

```
# Export the image, specifying scale and region.
class1export=class1.select('field')
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**{
    'image': class1export,
    'description': 'class1export',
    'folder':'GEE_Colab',
    'scale': 30,
    'region': shp
})
task.start()
```

```
# Export the image, specifying scale and region.
class1export=class1export.select('field')
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
    image=class1export,
    scale=30,
    fileFormat='GeoTIFF',
    description='class1export.tif',
    folder='GEE_Colab',
    maxPixels=1e9)
task.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is experiencing this issue, I found a solution.

```
shp = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xyz/shp')
out_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads')
filename = os.path.join(out_dir, 'class1export.tif')
roi=shp.geometry()
geemap.ee_export_image(class1export, filename=filename, scale=30, region=roi, file_per_band=False)
```